# facebook: own share button with different data

Tags: facebook, share, meta-tags

I want to make a custom Facebook share button on a website. I use this link:
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=title&p[url]=http://myurl.com&p[summary]=summary&p[images][0]=myimage

I have set the og Meta-Tags for sharing the main-site. But the Problem is that if I use the share Link above Facebook shows images/title/summary/etc from the Meta-Tags and not from the Link Parameters.

How can I force Facebook to use the data from the Parameters without changing/removing the Meta-Tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The sharer will no longer accept custom parameters and facebook will pull the information that is being displayed in the preview the same way that it would appear on facebook as a post, from the url OG meta tags.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/357750474364812/

You can use the feed dialog instead, but you would need to create an App for that: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog

Comment: How can I create an Facebook App that is only used for sharing custom sites? And can i share only links from one Website or simply everything?

Comment: what are "custom sites"? and yes, you can share everything.

Comment: instead of asking and waiting 12 hours for an answer, you could just try it ;)